# Scanf doesn't work with fork in a loop after the second iteration

Tags: c, fork, system, pid

I don't understand why scanf won't wait for input the second time in the loop. it only works in the first iteration. Also somewhat wait(&Status) won't print the correct Status.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() {
    int x ;
    int Status =-99;
    char* cmds[5];
    cmds[1] = "who";
    cmds[2] = "ls";
    cmds[3] = "date";
    cmds[4] = "kldsfjflskdjf";
    int i=10;
    while (i--) {
        printf("\nMenu:\n");
        printf("1)who \n"); printf("2)ls  \n");printf("3)date\n");
        printf("choice :");     
        scanf("%d", &x);

        int child = fork();
        if (child != 0) {
            execlp(cmds[x], cmds[x], NULL);
            printf("\nERROR\n");
            exit(99);
        } else {
            wait(&Status);
            printf("Status : %d", Status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait does not fill your int with the return status only. There is more data in this int. You should printf(..., WEXITSTATUS(Status)); ( You should avoid variable names starting with caps btw )

And it is the parent that receive child's PID, the child receive a 0. Your condition seems wrong.

Comment: If you are seeing `scanf` seem to bypass a read while calling in a loop, try changing the line: `scanf("%d", &x);` to `scanf(" %d", &x);`. (space before the `%d"`) When calling `scanf()` in a loop for some data types, it can pick up the `\n` character from user clicking return key.  The space consumes the newline character.

Comment: You should always cast the `NULL` argument to `execlp` to `char *`.

Comment: @mmeisson thanks! I understand now

Comment: @Barmar What's the purpose of making a cast on a NULL pointer there ?

Comment: @mmeisson `execl()` is a variadic function, so the argument type isn't declared and there's no automatic conversion. `#define NULL 0` is valid, and that will pass an `int` instead of `char *` if you don't write `(char *)NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comment posted above says, there are two problems here:

1. You're running the command in the parent, rather than the child. See the [fork manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).
2. wait does not give you the return code. It gives you an integer that you need to decode. See the [wait manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html).

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() {
    int x ;
    int Status =-99;
    char* cmds[6];
    cmds[1] = "who";
    cmds[2] = "ls";
    cmds[3] = "date";
    cmds[4] = "kldsfjflskdjf";
    int i=10;
    while (i--) {
        printf("\nMenu:\n");
        printf("1)who \n"); printf("2)ls  \n");printf("3)date\n");
        printf("choice :");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        int child = fork();
        if (child == 0) {
            execlp(cmds[x], cmds[x], NULL);
            printf("\nERROR\n");
            exit(99);
        } else {
            wait(&Status);
            printf("Status : %d", WEXITSTATUS(Status));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other than no `return` statement for a function that requires one, good answer.